# How can I execute multiple statements in a single function?

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming

I am learning Haskell and for an assignment I have to print a Snakes and Ladders game.  Starting out, I am trying to print the board and this is what I've done.

```
import Data.List
aRow :: Int -> String
aRow n = "+" ++ take (4*n) (intercalate "" (repeat "---+")) ++ "\n|" ++      take (4*n) (intercalate "" (repeat "   |")) ++ "\n"

board :: Int -> Int -> IO()
board 1 y = putStrLn (aRow y)
```

I would like another instance of board such that it takes arguments x and y

```
board x y = putStrLn (aRow y)
            board (x-1) y
```

I know that I can't just call multiple statements like this, but can anyone provide some insight about how I can go along with this? I want to call aRow with argument 'y' and do that 'x' times.

Thanks.

Also: when I call board 1 y I get this as output:
    board 1 5
    +---+---+---+---+---+
    |   |  |  |   |  |

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the cleanest way is to create the board without doing any `IO` and then at the end only to print it out using `IO`.

You can use `concat` and `replicate` to achieve this:

```
board :: Int -> Int -> String
board x y = concat (replicate y (aRow x))
```

You are probably missing a line at the bottom but I'll let you figure this out!

By the way, `take (4*n) (intercalate "" (repeat "---+"))` is the same as `concat (replicate n "---+")` so you could write `aRow` as:

```
aRow :: Int -> String
aRow n = '+' : concat (replicate n "---+")
      ++ "\n|" ++ concat (replicate n "   |")
      ++ "\n"
```

**Edit**: I would use `unlines :: [String] -> String` to concatenate several `String`s on multiple lines:

```
aRow :: Int -> String
aRow n = unlines
  [ '+' : concat (replicate n "---+")
  , '|' : concat (replicate n "   |")
  ]
```

Comment: I will find you, and I will hug you ('queue Liam Neeson voice').

Answer (score 3):

So you want to execute an `IO ()`, and then yet another `IO ()` action. Together they should be an `IO ()` as well. So you're looking for a combinator with signature `IO () -> IO () -> IO ()`. You can [ask Hoogle about this](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=IO+%28%29+-%3E+IO+%28%29+-%3E+IO+%28%29)... oh dear, that gives quite a lot of irrelevant results. But also [the right one, namely](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-62--62-)

```
(>>) :: Monad m => m a -> m b -> m b
```

Your `IO () -> IO () -> IO ()` is a special case of this signature, obtained by setting `m ~ IO` and `a ~ b ~ ()`. So, you can write

```
board x y = putStrLn (aRow y)
         >> board (x-1) y
```

Because these *monadic sequencing operators* are quite often used in Haskell, it has special syntactic-sugar syntax for them, namely

```
board x y = do
    putStrLn (aRow y)
    board (x-1) y
```

Ok so this works, but it's not really idiomatic. Manual recursion “loops” with a “counter variable” `x` are awkward and rather error-prone (you need to get the initial, termination and stepping conditions right). Really, all you're doing there is *execute the same action `x` times in a row*. So really you're interested in `Int -> IO () -> IO ()`. Again [ask Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Int+-%3E+IO+%28%29+-%3E+IO+%28%29); this time [the right result](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:replicateM) comes up a bit earlier...

```
replicateM_ :: Applicative m => Int -> m a -> m ()
```

so

```
board :: Int -> Int -> IO ()
board x y = replicateM_ x $ putStrLn (aRow y)
```

Even better, as Boomerang remarks, is to avoid IO looping altogether.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to sequence the two monadic functions:

```
board x y = putStrLn (aRow y) >> board (x - 1) y
```

or with `do` notation

```
board x y = do
    putStrLn (aRow y)
    board (x - 1) y
```

Note that `x == 0` makes a more natural base case:

```
board 0 y = return ()
board x y = do
   putStrLn (aRow y)
   board (x - 1) (aRow y)
```

See Boomerang's answer for a more idiomatic way of writing the function, though.